# In SQL adding two days & the outcome date must be a working day

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a calendar table with few fields out of which below fields are useful and want to add a new column "Promise date" with the below logic to the table. I am struggling with it and need help.

Example: Start Date = '01-02-2019' and then add two days. The result should be a working day.

Table Name := Date Table

Start Date, IsBillingday  = 1(Excluding holiday & weekends), WeekdayFlag = Weekday,  DayNameOfWeekShort = 'Mon'....Friday.

Started thinking simple  first...

```
CASE WHEN DayNameOfWeekShort = 'Mon' AND ISBillingDay = '1' THEN CONVERT (nvarchar(10) , DATEADD(Day , 2 , dbo.DateTable.StartDate) , 23) 
WHEN DayNameOfWeekShort = 'Tue' AND ISBillingDay = '1' THEN CONVERT (nvarchar(10) , DATEADD(Day , 2 , dbo.DateTable.StartDate) , 23) 
WHEN DayNameOfWeekShort = 'Wed' AND ISBillingDay = '1' THEN CONVERT (nvarchar(10) , DATEADD(Day , 2 , dbo.DateTable.StartDate) , 23) 
WHEN DayNameOfWeekShort = 'Thu' AND ISBillingDay = '1' THEN CONVERT (nvarchar(10) , DATEADD(Day , 4 , dbo.DateTable.StartDate) , 23) 
WHEN DayNameOfWeekShort = 'Fri' AND ISBillingDay = '1' THEN CONVERT (nvarchar(10) , DATEADD(Day , 5 , dbo.DateTable.StartDate) , 23) ELSE '' END
```

But then the result in some cases is not a working day...How to move to next working day?

For this line

```
CASE WHEN DayNameOfWeekShort = 'Mon' AND ISBillingDay = '1' THEN CONVERT (nvarchar(10) , DATEADD(Day , 2 , dbo.DateTable.StartDate) , 23)
```

The result is not a working day...Then need to add +1 day and check whether a working day or not...If not add + 1 ...If yes ..end loop.
a

Comment: You say you have a calendar table, correct? So I *assume* that that table says whether the day is a working day or not; so why not `LEAD` to the row the needed number of working days afterwards?

Comment: For Thu +4 and for Fri +3 should take you to Next Monday always.

Comment: Better sample data and logic would help.

Comment: For Thursday ..we should consider only 2 working days, then I should get Monday.  For friday...we should consider 2 working days, then I should get Tuesday.

Comment: FullDate  IsBillingDay Weekdayflag DayName PromiseDate Comment
1/01/2018 1 Weekday Tue 3/01/2018 Plus 2 days
2/01/2018 1 Weekday wed 8/01/2018 
3/01/2018 0 Weekday Thu 8/01/2018 Public holiday
4/01/2018 0 Weekday Fri 8/01/2018 Public holiday
5/01/2018 0 Weekend Sat N/A 
6/01/2018 0 Weekend Sun N/A 
7/01/2018 1 Weekday Mon 9/01/2018 
8/01/2018 1 Weekday Tue  
9/01/2018 1 Weekday wed  
10/01/2018 1 Weekday Thu

Comment: Example: Below date table has following columns

FullDate = 2/01/2018
IsBilling Day = 1
Weekday = Weekday
DayName = Wed
Promiseddate has to be calculated 
Which should be 4/01/2018 (friday). Need to check whether friday 4/01/2018 is a billing day. If not then move to next billing day

Answer (score 1):

If you want the next working day at least two days in the future, then you can use window functions.  I assume you have a flag to identify a working day.

The logic would look like:

```
select c.*,
       min(case when c.isworkingday = 1 then c.date end) over
           (order by c.date
            rows between 2 following and unbounded following)
           ) as next_workingday_plus_2
from calendar c;
```

Note that you should be storing dates as *dates* and not strings, particularly in a calendar table (unless you have one or more columns with dates in a particular format).